# `org-babel-params-from-properties' with a non-nil `no-eval' still evaluating functions

Tags: org-babel

I may be misunderstanding how the `no-eval` argument works, which is passed to `org-babel-parse-header-arguments`, and then finally `org-read` as `inhibit-lisp-eval`; it seems functions I'm using to pass the `:tangle` header a string value are still being evaluated with a non-nil `no-eval`. Are all header functions still evaluated at the very end?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking: can you provide an example of a code block that misbehaves? And how it misbehaves? Or are you doing something else entirely?

Comment: So one of my tangle functions checks whether a code block has already been tangled or not, and if not, it outputs a path determined by nearest org heading and its tree; in one of my files, I set a global property to this function, but since the function needs to expand the code block to see if it's been tangled yet, it encounters itself in the global headers, and the tangle process goes into an infinite loop. If I disable lisp evaluation using the `no-eval` argument, the loop goes away, but I'm wondering how the function is processed with no evaluation.

Comment: Why not add these details (and more - e.g. the function itself and the global property set to the function) to your question? IMO, it is too vague at this point (even with the extra information) to try to answer it: one would have to guess at your setup in order to try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: They're a lot of functions, and people tell me to provide a minimal, reproducible example, but I don't know how to reduce them any further...